# React Native TextInput two textContentType, emailAddress and username

Tags: ios, react-native

Hi is there a possibility to use two contenttype for IOS?

like have a suggestion of emails and possibility to access the keychain?

I have this kind of code at the moment, single contenttype is working surely. I'm not an IOS user so don't know if this is a normal way in daily life of IOS user but client needs this.

```
<TextInput
                  style={styles.modalInput}
                  placeholder="Email"
                  keyboardType="email-address"
                  textContentType={'emailAddress,username'}
                  placeholderTextColor='black'
                  autoCapitalize='none'
                  autoCorrect={false}
                  onChangeText={(value) => dispatch(setEmail(value))} />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is absolutely acceptable . **textContentType** is only applicable for IOS , whereas only one type can can be assigned to it. You can use either
*emailAddress* or *username* in that. I would recommend to use emailAddress as you are using keyboardType as email.

```js
<TextInput
                  style={styles.modalInput}
                  placeholder="Email"
                  keyboardType="email-address"
                  textContentType={'emailAddress'}
                  placeholderTextColor='black'
                  autoCapitalize='none'
                  autoCorrect={false}
                  onChangeText={(value) => dispatch(setEmail(value))} />
```